# Java: Empty constructor accepting a parameter

Tags: java, design-patterns, lazy-initialization

I try to understand the lazy initialization pattern described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization#Java). There is a constructor accepting a FRUIT_TYPE type argument.  While initializing, the hash map is being checked whether or not it already has a given fruit type and if not the constructor is used to create a fruit out of the given type. The fruit is then being put in the map. I copy-pasted the example and it worked fine. But how the fruit is being created without the (imo)necessary field for setting it to the given param in the constructor, e. g.

```
private FRUIT_TYPE fruitType;
private Fruit(FRUIT_TYPE type){this.fruitType = type}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's a broken example, in that you can't actually get the (unconventionally named) `FRUIT_TYPE` value from an arbitrary `Fruit` reference. The parameter and field are irrelevant, as nothing ever uses them. It does demonstrate lazy initialization, but badly.

Comment: @JonSkeet Where can I find a reliable example as it is not described in the GOF book?

Comment: Well you could easily add the assignment within the constructor, and maybe an instance method of `getFruitType()`, at which point it would be okay...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the individual Fruit instance in that example does not know its own type. In the contrived example, it does not need to know, since the type is neither inspected nor used at all.

I would strongly advise against following that example. It has multiple issues, not the least of which is the missing type field:

- Even the high-concurrency version is NOT thread-safe (see http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)
- It is highly contrived and hard to use. Something along these lines might match typical use cases more closely:

  ```
  class Fruit {
    private static final AtomicReference<Fruit> banana = new AtomicReference<>();
    private FruitType type;
    private Fruit(FruitType type) {this.type = type; someExpensiveCall(); }

    static Fruit getBanana() {
      Fruit b = banana.get();
      if (b == null) {
        banana.compareAndSet(null, new Banana());
        b = banana.get();
      }
      return b;
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: My intention was to point out that the example code was not correct even in the high concurrency version, not to revive that old debate.